# Как пропорционально уменьшить элементы карусели на малых разрешениях?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, carousel

Есть `owl-caruosel 2` карусель с 1 центральным элементом. Если на больших разрешениях все смотрится хорошо, то на малых почему-то ужасно - картинки изначально большого размера и не уменьшаются пропорционально, хоть сама карусель
адаптивная и в настройках карусели и указано свойство `responsive`.
Вопрос: как пропорционально уменьшить элементы?

```js
 var owl3 = $('#reviews');

 owl3.owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
   center: true,
   margin: 196,
   nav: true,
   autoWidth: true,
   navText: ["", ""],
   dots: false,
   responsive: {
     600: {
       items: 1
     },
     768: {
       items: 2
     },
     992: {
       items: 2
     },
     1200: {
       items: 2
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
#reviews .owl-item {
  margin: 30px auto 80px;
}
#reviews .owl-item .item img {
  box-shadow: 0 22px 87px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#reviews .owl-item.active.center {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section class="row" id="our-reviews">
  <div id="reviews" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задала:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;;
}
```

Получилось:

```js
var owl3 = $('#reviews');

owl3.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  center: true,
  margin: 196,
  nav: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  navText: ["", ""],
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    768: {
      items: 2
    },
    992: {
      items: 2
    },
    1200: {
      items: 2
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#reviews .owl-item {
  margin: 30px auto 80px;
}
#reviews .owl-item .item img {
  box-shadow: 0 22px 87px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#reviews .owl-item.active.center {
  opacity: 1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  
<section class="row" id="our-reviews">
  <div id="reviews" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: вот интересно - а почему это не работает здесь? http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/236/ и на основном сайте тоже?

Comment: @Вася,  а не пробовали заменить на мои js/css для owl карусели? Возможно с Вашими что-то не так? Попробовала только один js заменить и уже картинки уменьшились на малом разрешении!

Comment: а понял - у вас 1 версия карусели стоит, а у меня вторая. в первой невозможно сделать вот такое центрирование
http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/center.html
поэтому я взял вторую под задачу,оно у меня такое же изначально, и если раскрыть на большее разрешение - также центрируется изображение

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено! Нужно из общих настроек убрать и вынести позиции конкретно под интересующее разрешение, например `1200` вот так:

```
    1200: {
      items: 2,
      center: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      margin: 196
    }
```

Тогда работает - [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/vnpm1y06/237/)

```js
var owl3 = $('#reviews');

owl3.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  navText: ["", ""],
  dots: false,
  responsive: {
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    768: {
      items: 2
    },
    992: {
      items: 2
    },
    1200: {
      items: 2,
      center: true,
      autoWidth: true,
      margin: 196
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#reviews .owl-item {
  margin: 30px auto 80px;
}
#reviews .owl-item .item img {
  box-shadow: 0 22px 87px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#reviews .owl-item.active.center {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section class="row" id="our-reviews">
  <div id="reviews" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/707x349">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```